# Show recent posts in a table format

Tags: posts, table

In the index.php template I want to display posts in 3columns in a table format. How can I do this? I don't want a list format cause I have variable hight image sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use lists - just use proper CSS (every third li - first li in every row - should have `clear` property set; You can use CSS classes or :nth-child selector to do this).

If you really have to use table (I don't suggest it - it's not a very good idea, because it's not semantic), you can do something like this:

```
<table>
<?php while ( have_post() ): the_post(); ?>
  <php if ( $wp_query->current_post % 3 == 0 ): ?>
     <?php if ( $wp_query->current_post ): ?>
     </tr>
     <?php endif; ?> 
     <tr>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <td>
     ... YOUR POST GOES HERE
  </td>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $i = $wp_query->current_post; while ( $i % 3 != 0 ): $i++ ?><td></td><?php endwhile; ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Not tested it, so it can be a little bit buggy, but idea should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this can be done with a new WP_Query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
    // args
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );
    // new WP_Query
    $items_query = new WP_Query($args);        
    // loop
    if ($items_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($items_query->have_posts()) {
            $items_query->the_post();
            $content_items .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
            $content_items .= get_the_content();
        }
    }
    // echo 
    echo $content_items;
    // reset
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

You have to add the markup for your table inside the loop. You should give some more information about the direction you want your posts to appear to create a complete snippet. For example:

```
     ----------------------------------
     - 1st post - 2nd post - 3rd post -
     ----------------------------------
     - 4th post - 5th post - 6th post -
     ----------------------------------
     -   ....   -   ....   -   ...    -
     ----------------------------------
```

or

```
     ----------------------------------
     - 1st post - 3rd post - 5th post -
     ----------------------------------
     - 2nd post - 4th post - 6th post -
     ----------------------------------
     -   ....   -   ....   -   ...    -
     ----------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't think you should create your own custom WP_Query to show recent posts on index template. Recent posts are already selected in main $wp_query, so there is no need to select them again...

Comment: That's true, I only had "posts in 3columns in a table format" in mind, for recent posts in index.php you should use the mainquery.